# AccountName property of BlobClient in .net 6 returns empty string

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the following code to create an Azure blob client in C# using credentials.
When I try to retrieve the account name from the blobclient object it returns empty string, while if I use the connection string overload it returns the account name.
Any advise?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of `dfs`. If you use `blob` instead it will work.

```
var uri = new Uri("https://mystorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/");
var builder = new BlobUriBuilder(uri, true);
Console.WriteLine(builder.AccountName); // mystorageaccountname

var uri2 = new Uri("https://mystorageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/");
var builder2 = new BlobUriBuilder(uri2, true);
Console.WriteLine(builder2.AccountName); // null
```

If you think that is a bug, you can create a [bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/new/choose).